# How to get the properties from the list view tapped item context?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, nativescript

I have a master detail pages using a list view in the master page. I need to get the properties of the tapped item in a JavaScript function.
So far I get [object object]. What may I be missing?

```
<ListView row="1" col="0" items="{{ listings }}" itemTap="onItemTap" class="list-group">

<ListView.itemTemplate>

    <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="auto" columns="*, auto">
        <Label row="0" col="0" text="{{ title }}" class="list-item-header" />
        <Label row="0" col="1" class="page-icon fa" text="&#xf054;" />
    </GridLayout>
</ListView.itemTemplate>
```

```
const viewModel = new observableModule.fromObject({
    listings: info.listings || [],
    processing: info.processing || false
});

function onItemTap(args) {
const view = args.view;
const page = view.page;
const tappedItem = view.bindingContext;

try {
    page.frame.navigate({
            moduleName: "./mylistings/mylisting/mylisting",
            context: tappedItem,
            animated: true,
            transition: {
                name: "slide",
                duration: 200,
                curve: "ease"
            }
        });
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
}

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
page = args.object;

const myListing = observableModule.fromObject({
    listings: args.context
});
page.bindingContext = myListing.listings;

console.log(`myListing.listings: ${myListing.listings}`);
}
```

I tried:
    const mytitle = myListing.listings.title;
I get mytitle is undefined.

Comment: `tappedItem` should have the data for tapped item. I think the problem may be with your `navigate` call, may be something wrong with your module that throws exception. Can you share a Playground Sample for this issue?

Comment: tappedItem does have the data for the tapped item. That's the theory behind it. The issue I am having is getting it in the navigated to page. So, you find no issues with the code I posted?